# Octopus Deployment - only deploy some specific folders

Tags: deployment, continuous-deployment, dotnet, octopus-deploy

We are using [Octopus](https://octopus.com/) for our deployment to different environments. But we found that it always packages the complete solution and deploys it to the next level.
Is it possible to put some restrictions - like do not copy and deploy the config folders.
In our case we just need to deploy some specific folders and not the complete packaged solution. Is this possible with Octopus.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.. we can control the packages using nuspec file which will be added to your solution and you will be specifying the list of folders/files you dont wanna deploy. And you will use that nuspec to create the nuget package for deployments

Comment: Related question - https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/9449/11527

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, I think Octopus doesn't packages anything. The package should come from your CI Tool (Jenkins or TeamCity maybe?)

Having said that, I would *check on your previous step* in the CI/CD chain to see how are you packaging your solution, and filter those folders there, before packaging.

That will also help you:

- Reducing the package size
- Increase speed in the deployment process
- Avoid storing unnecessary files

**High-level suggested CI/CD Chain summary**

CI Tool

```
1. Compile/Test (if you're working with a compiled language)
2. Package only required folders
3. Push to Octopus
```

Octopus (CD Tool)

```
1. Store and manage final packages
```

Comment: Initially Octopus deploy was deploying .NET artifacts only... Now I think Octopus deploy supports for Java, python as well

Comment: Related question - https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/9449/11527