# Octopus server installation on Linux

Tags: deployment, continuous-deployment, octopus-deploy

I learnt that,

Octopus server can be installed on Windows 2008, 2012, 2016 server editions

I see msi packages on Download page

---

Can Octopus server be installed on Ubuntu?

Can tentacle software be installed on Linux box?

Comment: Sure, you can run Windows in a VM.  https://octopus.com/docs/installation sounds very Windows specific to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2023-04-16 this answer is out of date, [Diego Marinelli's answer](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/13727/397) should be accepted as correct.

### Original Answer

<s>Historically Octopus Deploy was a solution to deploy software on Windows only, therefore the server component only supports installation on Windows.</s>

This is for a couple of [technical reasons](https://octopus.com/docs/installation/requirements):

1. Octopus Server takes a hard dependency on Internet Information Services (IIS) which itself only runs on Windows.
2. Octopus Server is written in the .NET Framework doesn't run on Linux.

Once you have the Octopus Deploy Server software installed, you can [manage Linux hosts via SSH](https://octopus.com/docs/infrastructure/deployment-targets/linux), you don't need tentacles to manage Linux hosts.

Comment: Octopus server was available from On-prem infra days...Now, we are using public cloud like AWS... Does the approach change in installation setup of Octopus server, to deploy resources in public cloud?

Comment: They have a cloud offering (https://octopus.com/pricing/cloud) which essentially is a managed service, you pay them $45+ per month to get access to a console.  I, however, have never used it, as it's never been a viable option for my use case.  Other than that, if you want to deploy your own Octopus Server to AWS you would just create Windows EC2 instances.

Comment: For cloud agnostic(AWS, GCP,Azure) deployment orchestration, Do you consider Octopus as a solution?

Comment: It depends, if you fall into one of the following two camps then yes: (a) you have an existing investment in Octopus Deploy, i.e. skills, licences, etc. (b) you have sizable Windows estate to manage either in the cloud or on-prem.  If you don't fit into that specification then something like spinnaker.io would be an option or even a more generalist tool such as Jenkins.

Comment: jenkins + ansible for deployment orchestration needs lot of coding in ansible

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve, my experience if you are trying to automate something that many other people have already done then it's either supported out-of-the-box in Octopus or available on Ansible Galaxy.  If you are trying to do work that is unique to you, or at least uncommon, then you are going to be writing a lot of something, whether that's Ansible/Puppet/Chef, Scripts, Terraform, etc and running them with Octopus.

Comment: This answer is not up to date.

Comment: Correct, it is no longer accurate. I have updated my post and linked to Diego Marinelli.

Answer (score 4):

The document, [Octopus Server Linux Container](https://octopus.com/docs/installation/octopus-in-container/octopus-server-container-linux) provides detailed instructions on how to operate Octopus Server on Linux using an image provided by Octopus Deploy on Docker Hub:

> Octopus Server Linux Containers launched as part of 2020.6 and it's our recommended way to use containers with Octopus Deploy.